# Transparent control not capturing mouse events

Tags: wpf

I have a window with a transparent background (not `null`). Inside that window, I have a user control, also with a transparent background.

The window receives mouse events, but the user control does not.

If I change the background of the user control from `Transparent` to `#01000000`, then the user control starts to receive mouse events. However, controls hosted within the user control (which are themselves visible) never receive mouse events, regardless of the user control's background.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use Snoop, attach and look at the "Events" tab to see what events are being propagated and to where.

Comment: @codekaizen Snoop showed that the reason child controls were not receiving events was because there was another control on top of them which was taking the events. Still not sure why Transparent backgrounds are not receiving events.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something handling the event or you have some configuration issue, since it works ok for me: http://share.linqpad.net/ijx3vb.linq. ([Get Linqpad free.](http://www.linqpad.net/GetFile.aspx?LINQPad4Setup.exe))

```
var t = new TextBlock() { Text = "test" };

var uc1 = new UserControl() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) };
uc1.MouseEnter += (s, args) => { t.Text = "UC1"; };

var uc2 = new UserControl() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(01, 00, 00, 00)) };
uc2.MouseEnter += (s, args) => { t.Text = "UC2"; };

var g = new Grid();
g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
g.Children.Add(t);
g.Children.Add(uc1);
g.Children.Add(uc2);

Grid.SetRow(t, 0);
Grid.SetRow(uc1, 1);
Grid.SetRow(uc2, 2);

PanelManager.DisplayWpfElement(g);
```